# I can not refer to the SharedPreferences from DDL when first install

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, deferred-deep-linking

I have finished implementing [Deferred deep linking](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/12373942?hl=en#zippy=%2Csteps-to-activate-ddl-in-the-gaf-sdk) in my android app. But during the first install, app cannot get getSharedPreferences in the Activity. Even though the shared_pref file already exists. This will be normal when the app is closed first after install. So the DDL implementation is not expected. How do I solve it?

The expectation is that when user first install, the deeplink from the shared_pref Deferred Deep Linking should be immediately readable.